# Using recursion to find number of vowels

Tags: python, recursion

I need to use recursion to find the number of vowels in a string. So if `hello` is entered I want it to return `2`.

The problem I'm having is going to the next character in the string.

```
 def recVowelCount(i):
    count = 0
    if i in 'aeiou':
        count +=1
        reVowelCount(i)
    else:
        reVowelCount(i)
        return count
```

Comment: Why does it need to use recursion?  This is not a good use-case for recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using recursion :)

```
def recVowelCount(i, chars_to_find='aeiou'):
    if not chars_to_find:
        return 0
    return i.count(chars_to_find[0]) + recVowelCount(i, chars_to_find[1:])
```

Now, the problem in your code is that

```
if i in 'aeiou':
```

would be asking `if 'hello' in 'aeiou':`, which isn't very useful. You need to check `if i[0] in 'aeiou'` where `i[0]` will be each letter of `"hello"` each time the function is called recursively

Start with the simple case. What happens if the input string is empty? You'd just return `0` right?

```
def recVowelCount(i):
    if not i:
        return 0
```

So we're half done. Now you need to think about what happens in the case the `i` isn't empty. If the first character is a vowel, we'll count `1` and then pass the rest of the string into the function recursively

```
def recVowelCount(i):
    if not i:
        return 0
    if i[0] in 'aeiou':
        count = 1
    else:
        count = 0
    return count + recVowelCount(i[1:])
```

ok.. that can be refactored a little

```
def recVowelCount(i):
    if not i:
        return 0
    count = 'aeiou'.count(i[0])
    return count + recVowelCount(i[1:])
```

and finally

```
def recVowelCount(i):
    if not i:
        return 0
    return 'aeiou'.count(i[0]) + recVowelCount(i[1:])
```

Comment: Nipped the issue in the bud with `if 'hello' in 'aeiou':`

Answer (score 2):

```
def recVowelCount(s):
    ''' Return number of vowels in string s'''
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    letter = s[0]
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        return 1 + recVowelCount(s[1:])
    return recVowelCount(s[1:])


print recVowelCount('hello')
```

There are 3 basic steps in any recursive program:

1. base case
2. you need to progress towards base case
3. recursive call

Answer (score 1):

first of all its not clear what argument you are passing
    `def countVowels(my_string):`
is probably a better way to start

next you need a base case

```
 if len(my_string) == 1:
    if my_string in "aeiou": return 1
    else:return 0
```

then you need your recursion

```
 elif my_string[0] in "aeiou":
     return 1 + countVowels(my_string[1:])
 else:
      return 0 + countVowels(my_string[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_vowels(word=None, count=0):
    if word:
        if word[0] in ('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u'):
            count += 1
        return find_vowels(word=word[1:], count=count)
    else:
        return count
```

`find_vowels('python is awesome')`

`find_vowels` function takes two parameters - One is `word`, which is the actual string to lookup. The other is `count`, which contains total occurrences of vowels. Initial value for `count` is set to 0.

If `word` is empty, function will return count value. This is when `word` has been completely checked for vowels.
 `if word:`

The following block contains the actual logic. The first character is repeatedly checked in `word`. If it is a vowel, `count` argument is incremented.

`return find_vowels(word=word[1:], count=count)` is where the recursion happens. Using `word=word[1:]` we slice the first character since it has been checked.

**Example**:

let `word ='Python'`

This how value of `word` looks in subsequent calls:

`Python` - 1st call
`ython`  - 2nd call
`thon`   - 3nd call
`hon`    - 4th call
`on`     - 5th call
`n`      - 6th call
      - last call(Empty)

Finally when string is empty, `count` is returned.

This is called tail recursion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call